# How to get URL with routing for .net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an application on port 9907, but I'm using routing to all my apps available through 9900 port with different aliases. 
I need to get URL for my application for some ferther interaction. So I've make it like this in my controller class:

```
string startAppTicks = HttpContext.Session.Get<long>(Extensions.SessionExtensions.INSTANCE_UNIQUE_KEY).ToString();
string link = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host.Value + "/Download?sessionId=" + startAppTicks;
```

Resulted link is https://localhost:9907/Download?sessionId=637159953129209084

But I've expected to get https://10.132.x.x:9900/Download?sessionId=637159953129209084

(Expected ip instead of localhost, routed port 9900 instead of original one 9907)

Please help with this code

Comment: I think you can get ip `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`

Comment: and `Request.Url.Port`